# How to Assign Values to Tensorflow SubTensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, subset, variable-assignment

I have a tensorfow constant

```
x = tf.zeros((N * (T - n + 1), n, D))
```

I have a tensorflow placeholder:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, n_in))
```

And I want to assign some valued of X to x, in numpy I would do:

```
x[N * i:N * (i + 1), :, :] = X[:, i:i + n, :]
```

How do I do that in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assign array chunks with `numpy` and then converting back to `tensorflow`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:   
    #some tf operations here       
    # ...

    x_np = np.array(sess.run(x))
    X_np = np.array(sess.run(X))

    #assign with numpy:
    x_np[N * i:N * (i + 1), :, :] = X_np[:, i:i + n, :]

    x_result = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_np)
```

Comment: Ya, that is possible, but in my case I need to do it inside a graph with placeholders which I dont yet know how big they would be, so I really need to do inside tensorflow itself, outside of a session. (I do it while building my neural network so I cant have an open session yet...)

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse Well, now I also have faced with similar problem (thus much easier). I use 'tf.concat' from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slicing-and-joining

Comment: Olia_Pavliuk could you edit your answer to show how you do it exactly?

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse I'm afraid it doesn't solve your problem, because I don't use slicing. :(

    x1  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, R1])
    y1 = tf.matmul(x1, l1_W1) + l1_b1
    
    x2  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, R2])
    y2 = tf.matmul(x2, l1_W2) + l1_b2

    yy = tf.concat(1, [y1, y2])

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse You just might see the link above, because it shows possibilities for slicing in TF.

Comment: Olia: ya, it's only half of the solution ;) But thank you anyways :)